# YAML alias change value

Tags: python, yaml

```
a = '''
test: &test
    a: 1
    b: 2
test1:
    <<: *test
    a: 2
'''
dict = yaml.load(a)
dict['test']['a'] = 3
dict['test']['b'] = 4
print dict
```

this print `{'test': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'test1': {'a': 2, 'b': 2}}`

but I want to print `{'test': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'test1': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}`

How can I change the `dict['test1']` value when I change `dict['test']`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the merge keys operation `<<: *ref`, the yaml loader will  create a dict, and just copy the items in from the referenced dict, if the key doesn't already exist. Then changes to then referenced dict don't change the new dict. There is no way around this.

A straight forward reference will not create a copy. E.g.:

```
a = '''
test: &test
    a: 1
    b: 2
test1: *test
'''
dict = yaml.load(a)
dict['test']['a'] = 3
dict['test']['b'] = 4
print(dict)

{'test': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'test1': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
```

Comment: There is no copy of `dict` made in ruamel.yaml nor in PyYAML when merging, which library are you referring to that makes a copy, PySyck? In both ruamel.yaml and PyYAML, the `dict`  that is created in the compositing phase is checked for the merge key and if there, that dict  is "flattened" by inserting **in the already created dict** the key-value pairs for keys that are not yet available in the dict. No copy is made of any **newly** created dict in that process

Comment: And the semantics of making a reference is of course completely different, in your example the value for `a` in `test1` will never be `2` during the run of the program

Comment: @anthon - I'm guessing you wrote your first comment before I edited my answer. I realized that mistake, and fixed it.  I don't get your second comment. I never say `a` will be `2`.

Comment: In the OP's  code, directly after the load `dict['test1']['a'] == 2` in your code this never holds true.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work as **merges are resolved in the composing step of the load**.

The actually key-value pairs of the mapping that is the value for
`test` are inserted in the key-value pairs of the mapping that is the
value for `test1`, but only if that value doesn't already exist (from
the `test1` mapping itself or from any previous merges if a list is
specified)

So `a` under `test1` never even gets the value `1` let alone the value `3`

What you can do is merge the new value of `b`, into your `test1`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.compat import StringIO

yaml = YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4)

a = """\
test: &ta
    a: 1
    b: 2
test1:
    <<: *ta
    a: 2
"""

data = yaml.load(a)
data['test']['a'] = 3
data['test']['b'] = 4

buf = StringIO()
yaml.dump(data, buf)

yaml2 = YAML(typ='safe')
print(yaml2.load(buf.getvalue()))
```

which gives:

```
{'test': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, 'test1': {'a': 2, 'b': 4}}
```

Important:

- It is not a good idea to mask a Python builtin, so don't use `dict` as variable name
- It is more customary to use `"""` for multiline strings, and make sure you escape
  the newline on the first line if you don't want the file to start with an empty line
- Python 2.7 is going end-of-life in 2020. Even if you have to use it get used to 
  using the `print()` function instead of using the `print` statement: use the 
  `from __future__` line in **all** your python2 code.
- Don't obscure things by using the same strings for keys and
  anchors. With your example if you refer to `test` there is no way of
  knowing, without context, whether you mean the one or the other.